# changing value of a float in python for loop

Tags: python, immutability

Python types are still surprising, after some experience with Python scripting!
In the following loop:

```
import random
very_large_number = 10000000
for i in xrange(very_large_number):
    variable = random.random()
    print id(variable)
```

it looks like I'm creating 10000000 variables!
Is there any way to keep only one variable in memory and just change its value?

Comment: be sure to use `xrange` instead of `range`. `range` creates a list of numbers 0 .. very_large_number, and that's what actually eats your memory.

Comment: @miraculixx `range` is fine if OP uses python3.x

Comment: @miraculixx Thanks for this, I edited this

Comment: because numbers are immutable types, there is no way to keep the id (and memory) and reassign another value. See:
https://docs.python.org/3.1/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: @Niemerds Thanks,  is there a mutable object equivalent to `float`?

Comment: @altroware there is no need. What you are doing (when using `xrange` in Py 27) is perfectly fine. The GC takes care of deleting objects if they are no longer referenced, as AlokThakur's answer suggests.

Comment: At least I'm not aware of anything like this. If you intend to pass some number as a "reference parameter" you might put it inside a list or a class instance. If you wan't to avoid garbage collecting the numbers memory for efficiency reasons, I curiously wait for someone else insights.

Comment: Ok, I can accept---of course!---as answer that it is impossible to change immutable types, but I wonder why such choice was made and if a loop like the one in the question has bad performances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables are not kept in memory. Python does reference counting - so on my machine I just got the output:

```
...
29337248
29337272
29337248
29337272
...
```

See the pattern? The interpreter re-uses memory.

As for immutability - well, this is a feature actually. As long as something references this number, it will not go away. If you assign to a reference, all other references still point to the original value.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you create a new variable (e.g. `variable = random.random()`), it is assigned to a new location in memory.  Because you are reassigning this variable through your loop, the old variable goes out of scope and eventually gets garbage collected away.  You are merely printing the memory location of each new allocation.  This does not mean every memory location printed is still active.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to simulate your problem :-

```
>>> import random
>>> very_large_number = 10
>>> for i in xrange(very_large_number):
    variable = random.random()
    print id(variable)


37663064
31924560
37663064
31924560
37663064
31924560
37663064
31924560
37663064
31924560
```

As expected, Memory is cleaned and reclaimed. Python garbage collector check for reference count, If there is no reference then object would be deleted from memory.

Comment: Great that answer to the first part of my question! I wish also to know explicitly if/how it is possible to change value to a variable.

Comment: That is not possible with immutable type, If you use any mutable type like list then you can achieve what you want.